# How to share code between node.js apps?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have several apps in node that all share a few modules that I've written. These modules are not available via npm.  I would like to be able to share freely between apps, but I don't want to copy directories around, nor rely on Git to do so.  And I'm not really big on using symlinks to do this either.

I would like to arrange directories something like this:

```
app1
 server.js
 node_modules
  (public modules from npm needed for app1)
 lib
  (my own modules specific to app1)

app2
 server.js
 node_modules
  (public modules from npm needed for app2)
 lib
  (my own modules specific to app2)

shared_lib
 (my own modules that are used in both app1 and app2)
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the modules in shared_lib seem to get confused as to where to find the modules that will be in the node_modules directory of whichever app they are running in.  At least I think that is the problem.

So....what is a good way to do this that avoids having duplicates of files?  (note that I don't care about duplicates of things in node_modules, since those aren't my code, I don't  check them into Git, etc)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've got this working by having **node_modules** folders at different levels - node then automatically traverses upwards until it finds the module.

Note you don't have to publish to npm to have a module inside of node_modules - just use:

```
"private": true
```

Inside each of your private **package.json** files - for your project I would have the following:

```
app1
 server.js
 node_modules
  (public modules from npm needed for app1)
  (private modules locally needed for app1)

app2
 server.js
 node_modules
  (public modules from npm needed for app2)
  (private modules locally needed for app2)

node_modules
  (public modules from npm needed for app1 & app2)
  (private modules locally for app1 & app2)
```

The point is node.js has a mechanism for dealing with this already and it's awesome.  Just combine it with the 'private not on NPM' trick and you are good to go.

In short a:

```
require('somemodule')
```

From app A or B would cascade upwards until it found the module - regardless if it lived lower down or higher up.  Indeed - this lets you hot-swap the location without changing any of the **require(...)** statements.

[node.js module documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: When I tried this, any modules required by the shared modules could not be resolved. In your structure, it looks like the highest node_modules folder has both private (checked into source control) and public (npm install'd - not checked in) modules. I don't normall check public modules into source control - how did you get around this?

Answer (score 53):

The npm documentation recommends using [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) to create your own Node.js packages locally, and then making them available to other Node.js applications. It's a simple four-step process.

A typical procedure would be to first create a package with the following structure:

```
  hello
  | index.js
  | package.json
```

A typical implementation of these files would be:

index.js

```
  exports.world = function() {
     return('Hello World');
  }
```

package.json

```
  {
    "name": "hello",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "engines": {
    "node": "v0.6.x"
    }
  }
```

"private:true" ensures that npm will refuse to publish the package. This is a way to prevent accidental publication of private packages.

Next, navigate to the root of your Node.js package folder and run `npm link` to link the package globally so it can be used in other applications.

To use this package in another application, e.g., "hello-world", with the following directory structure:

```
 hello-world
 | app.js
```

Navigate to the hello-world folder and run:

```
 npm link hello
```

Now you can use it like any other npm package like so:

app.js

```
  var http = require('http');
  var hello = require('hello');

  var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     res.writeHead(200);
     res.end(hello.world());
  });
  server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: How does this work when deploying to a PaaS environment such as Heroku or Nodejitsu?

Comment: npm link won't work in a PaaS environment. Heroku honours node modules that are pushed in with your code. So that might be an option.

Comment: That's what I don't get - if you deploy to Heroku from git, you don't check your node_modules in. Also, that would imply that you copy you shared code into the node_modules folder before you check in. Which seems cumbersome and error prone. Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: That seems the only way out. The npm link option is only available if you have access to the remote terminal over ssh... as in AWS or Rackspace

Comment: Ok, I think the way to go is using dependencies defined as git repos or tarballs, then use npm link to make life easier during development... Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: I think you can use webpack to package the whole thing together for that purpose

Answer (score 6):

Just use the correct path in your require call

For example in server.js that would be:

> var moduleName = require('../shared_lib/moduleName/module.js');

Its Important to know that as soon as your path is prefixed with '/', '../', or './' the path is relative to the calling file.

For further information about nodes module loading visit:
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html

Comment: But if I do that, and then that module tries to require a module that comes from npm, it gets confused and gives errors.

Comment: no answer? that's because you tried to build something more complicated than a demo with Node

Comment: this works great with esbuild targeting to lambda :thumbsup

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can reference shared_lib from app1, but then you run into a problem if you want to package and deploy app1 to some other environment, such as a web server on AWS.

In this case, you're better off installing your modules in shared_lib to app1 and app2 using "npm install shared_lib/module". It will also install all the dependencies of the shared_lib modules in app1 and app2 and deal with conflicts/duplicates.

See this:
[How to install a private NPM module without my own registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry)

Answer (score 3):

If you check out the [node.js docs](http://nodejs.org/docs), you'll see that Node.js understands the `package.json` file format as well, at least cursorily.

Basically, if you have a directory named `foo`, and in that directory is a `package.json` file with the key-value pair: `"main": "myCode.js"`, then if you try to `require("foo")` and it finds this directory with a `package.json` file inside, it will then use `foo/myCode.js` for the `foo` module.

So, with your directory structure, if each shared lib has it's own directory with such a simple `package.json` file inside, then your apps can get the shared libs by:

```
var lib1 = require('../shared_lib/lib1');
var lib2 = require('../shared_lib/lib2');
```

And that should work for both of these apps.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be cloning files from the other places into this repo:

**clone.js**:

```js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const shared = [
  {
    type: 'file',
    source: '../app1',
    files: [
      'src/file1',
      'src/file2',
      '...'
    ],
  },
]

function cloneFiles(source, files) {
  const Reset = '\x1b[0m'
  const FgGreen = '\x1b[32m'
  console.log(`---------- Cloning ${files.length} files from ${source} ----------`)

  for (const file of files) {
    const sourceFile = path.join(__dirname, '..', source, file)
    const targetFile = path.join(__dirname, '..', file)

    process.stdout.write(` ${file} ... `)
    fs.copyFileSync(sourceFile, targetFile)
    console.log(`${FgGreen}Done!${Reset}`)
  }

  console.log(`---------- All done successfully ----------\n`)
}

;(() => {
  for (const item of shared) {
    switch (item.type) {
      case 'file':
        cloneFiles(item.source, item.files)
        break
    }
  }
})()
```

Then, in the **package.json** you can add this script and call it when you want to clone / sync files:

```json
"clone": "node clone.js"
```