# configure custom module for Node.js project

Tags: node.js

I create my Node project (npm init). In this project, i want to use Node REST Client from git hub https://github.com/dchester/node-rest-client.

1. update package.json with dependency:

   ...
        "dependencies": {
           "rest-client": "*"
         },
   ...
2. create dir node_modules in my project
3. Copy the rest-client into the directory 'node_modules'
4. Run 'npm install' to install this dependency, however it doesn't.
   What am i doing wrong? how to properly install dependency that is not from npm central repo?

Thank You

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? As far as I know all npm install does is download the module so placing it in your node_modules folder and adding the dependency should do it. Just include the module (`require('rest-client')`) in your program.

Comment: ...it silently fails unless i manually go into the node_modules/rest-client and run 'npm install'....its okey for one module, but if i had dozen?...i must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'll have to do it manually for every module. However as the accepted answer in [How to install a private NPM module without my own registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry) by Mihai points out, npm knows about git:

```
npm install git://github.com/visionmedia/express.git
```

furthermore, besides going into the directory and typing `npm install` there it is possible to specify the path as argument:

```
npm install path/to/somedir
```

There's another useful answer in [How to install a private NPM module without my own registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry) where you can see you can also specify a url pointing to a tarball. I suggest you take a look at that thread.