# How to depend on private packages in node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to create modules in a private (password protected) git repository, but also be able to have different projects depend on that module (the dependencies in package.json). How can I use private modules when doing npm install? Will npm install ask you for the password for a particular repository? In the past, whenever I've seen a password prompt in npm, it presents the prompt for a password (potentially multiple times) but the output just plows over the prompt. This experience makes me worried that npm doesn't handle this case very gracefully.

So whats the right way to do this?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10391718/1048697

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a private NPM module without my own registry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry)

Comment: I can certainly create my own registry, or link to a git repository tar file, but the "git+ssh://git@github.com:myaccount/myprivate.git" form has caused problems for me in the past. Any answers specifically about password input for private repos accessed by npm?