# Use modified library in node_modules when deploying to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I am building an app in nodejs and making use of a library called nodify-shopify which is used to interact with the shopify api
The library hasn't implemented all the api calls so i had to implement it myself

when i push my app to heroku, it doesn't go with the modified library in node_modules so my app breaks

What's the best way to solve this?
I have considered making a pull request, but the project seems abandoned and i need to do this fast.
I have also considered adding the node_modules to version control, but I'm wondering if there's a better way?
I need to get this done fast too, so time is of essence
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish you version of the library somewhere it could be found during the heroku deployment. Npm supports a variety of possibilities to load node module:

- (g)zip packages
- [git checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10391718/45786)