# How to add shared library in InteliliJ / WebStorm that will be part of git submit?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

How to add shared library in InteliliJ / WebStorm that will be part of git submit?

I want to add an external library that I can share among many WebStorm packages.
However, I still want that external package (let's say backbone) to be included as part of my project so when I submit to GitHub it will be part of everything that's uploaded to the repository.

At the same time, if I make a change to Backbone, everyone (every project) should get my change and even upload to common remote ftp.

is that possible?

only way I can think of is to setup a local sync using Gulp, but wondering is there is a better way?

regards,

Sean.

Comment: I would not recommend that you put that anywhere in that repository - use dependency management.  In order to give you the clearest advice, it'd be best to know what kind of third party library you're talking about, and why you think that modifying it is the correct solution to begin with.

Comment: Even if it's my own lib, that I share against many projects, how would you solve that?

Comment: Set up a private Git repo (either public or private, depending on what's in it), and [add it as a private dependency to the overall project.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10391718/1079354)