# Own node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, npm, node-modules

i am planning a new application i want to build it completely modular. So i have my main app and want to separate units as node_modules.

```
+ app_module
  - package.json # dependencies: delivery_mdoule, order_module, ..
  + node_modules/
    + delivery_module/
    + order_module/

+ delivery_module
  - package.json
  - index.js
  + lib/
  + node_modules/
  - ...

+ order_module
  - package.json
  - index.js
  + lib/
  + node_modules/
  - ...
```

At first step the modules will be on the same directory, but the next step is to oursource the modules to own repositorys. i must include it local over package.json. Is that possible?

Comment: look at this - private npm nodules http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry