# Add local project dependency for npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

What is the proper syntax to add local project dependency in npm `package.json` file?

I have git project locally in `C:\projects\MyApp`

I want to get this project with `npm install`. I tried following

```
"dependencies": {
  .....
  "my-app": "file://../projects/MyApp/MyApp.git"
  .....
 }
```

but getting error

```
Could not install ....
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: there is a typo in the question above: 'dependencioes'

Comment: corrected the typo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally got it working

```
"my-app": "../projects/MyApp"
```

Its' simple until you know.

Answer (score 2):

Local dependency has to be a directory on your filesystem.

---

Alternately there is [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

Excerpt from the docs:

> Package linking is a two-step process.
>
> First, npm link in a package folder will create a globally-installed
>   symbolic link from prefix/package-name to the current folder (see
>   npm-config for the value of prefix).
>
> Next, in some other location, npm link package-name will create a
>   symlink from the local node_modules folder to the global symlink.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> cd ~/projects/node-redis    # go into the package directory
> npm link                    # creates global link
> cd ~/projects/node-bloggy   # go into some other package directory.
> npm link redis              # link-install the package
> ```

Answer (score 0):

File is the wrong protocol. You can use git+ssh or git+https.
Here can you find more information about your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10391718/5111420

and I see a typo: dependencioes -> dependencies

Comment: ahh, I have your question misunderstood, because I did not have the one sentence in focus: "I have git project locally in C:\projects\MyApp"