# JetBrains: Share the same folder between projects

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

My TypeScript project consists of two parts: a client and a server. Both should share code (like types, domain specific functions) and so I'd like to create a `core` package that can be consumed by them.

I found out that this is more complicated than one might think, especially when it comes to CI and stuff.

So the *easiest* solution I can think about would be a single folder that is synchronized between my projects: If I edit a file in one project, the changes will be reflected immediately in the other project (since they refer to the same file). And yes, when it comes to version control, both projects will contain their own copy.

Is this possible with JetBrains IntelliJ / WebStorm?

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Directories --> Add Content Root` I guess... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-project-structure.html#adding_content_root

Comment: Thank you, but then the folder doesn't exist within the single projects and so the code will be missing in Git/CI, right?

Comment: I guess so. P.S. You can have multiple VCS roots: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/enabling-version-control.html#associate_directory_with_VCS **P.P.S.** Symlinks anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why do you want a separate copy of the `core` package for each project when it comes to version control. That's not the way it should handle. I'll suggest a better way to do this.

You have to use a dependency manager like `npm` for your projects (most probably you may using it already). Create 3 separate modules(projects) called `client`, `server` and `core`. Then add `package.json` for each project. Then you can add `core` module as a dependency for `server` and `client` modules. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816241/add-local-project-dependency-for-npm-install) for adding local dependencies to `package.json` if you are not aware of it.

But if you really, really want to stick to your method (keep your files synchronized) you can do it by creating a deployment profile (Tools > Deployment > Configuration > Click on + > Local or mounted folder) on Intellij Idea / WebStrom and enable automatic deployment.

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact, I'd be very happy if there would be a better way. However, this "local package" approach fails when it comes to CI, for instance. How can I make my `core` package available there? How will the development / production workflow be then?

Comment: Ideally there should be one project (one VCS root) with 3 modules (sub directories). So you can just add version control to project directory where there will be only one repository. When it comes to CI/CD you can define it with 3 steps to build each module.

Comment: If you are really uncomfortable with one-project-3-modules approach, you can host a private npm registry and configure CI/CD to publish `core` package to it. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575627/can-you-host-a-private-repository-for-your-organization-to-use-with-npm). Then access core module from `client` and `server` module just like any other npm package.