# Git clone not working with npm

Tags: git, ssh, docker, npm

I am trying to clone a private Git repo from npm inside a Docker container but am getting an error `Permission denied (publickey)`.

I generated a SSH key with this command on my host machine:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myname@mydomain.com"
```

Then I added this to Bitbucket, `ssh-add`-ed it, and tested it with `git clone` and everything worked fine (on the host machine). I also tried `npm install` in my project folder and all git cloning was fine.

I copied the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files to another folder and I mount this folder to `/root/.ssh` when doing `docker run`. The problem now is that `npm install` gives a permission denied error when trying to clone from that private Git repo.

I went into the container with bash and tried `npm install` manually, but got the same error. I made sure that `ssh-agent` was up by running `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and then made sure the key was added by running `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Then I tried it again, but the same issue.

The thing though is that if, in the same container, I try just a regular `git clone ...` then it clones fine! No problems or anything. I know it is using the SSH key since if I remove it from Bitbucket, I get a permission denied error. Then if I re-add it to Bitbucket, it clones fine.

How do I get npm to clone properly? The working (inside the container) git clone command I use is:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:org/repo.git
```

and the npm repo dependency line is:

```
"repo": "git+ssh://bitbucket.org/org/repo.git"
```

The full npm error is:

```
npm ERR! git clone ssh://bitbucket.org/org/repo.git Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-bitbucket-org-org-repo-git-3f459951'...
npm ERR! git clone ssh://bitbucket.org/org/repo.git Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone ssh://bitbucket.org/org/repo.git fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone ssh://bitbucket.org/org/repo.git 
npm ERR! git clone ssh://bitbucket.org/org/repo.git Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone ssh://bitbucket.org/org/repo.git and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`git+ssh://bitbucket.org/org/repo.git`" does not look like a valid ssh url.

"`git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/{user}/{repository}.git`" is.

Check if you can [change the npm repo dependency url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10391718/6309).
(and/or `npm install -S "git+https://username@github.com/orgname/repositoryname.git"`)

Comment: After all the searching, this is the correct answer. I just had to add "git@" before bitbucket in the URL and it was fine. Thank you!