# How to npm install a private github repo from my own organization?

Tags: git, github, docker, npm, dockerhub

I am a member of an organization on Github and am trying to set up a automated build process on Docker Hub for one of my repos - say module foo.

In my package.json for foo, I have a dependency on a module, say bar, that is also a repo of the same organization on Github that I need to pull.

All these repos are private.

I am confused on how to set this up. I do not want to change the SSH settings of my user account, since I do not want other users of the organization to be able to access my other personal private repos.

The other option is to set up deploy keys, but how do I do this for Docker Hub machine that is doing the build?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a private NPM module without my own registry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I am not trying to install from an npm registry. I want to use package.json's method of installing from a private github repo, that belongs to an organization I am a member of.

Comment: The dup solution shows how to do that..

Comment: I've experienced the same pain points as you on this.  We ended up creating a dev-ops user in github and adding them to our organization.  Then we created a personal access token for that user that we use in our package.json files for pulling private organization scoped repos.  It would be better if github let you create personal access tokens for orgs.

Comment: basically like this:  "bar": "git+https://<ops_user_personal_token_here>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/orgname/bar.git"

Comment: I guess here lies the problem. <ops_user_personal_token> will offer access to all of <ops> personal repos. I just want the organization's private repos token. Not sure if this is possible without the workaround mentioned by @Colin Estes