# Can NPM suggest additional and optional packages after `npm install` command?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install

Can NPM suggest to install additional and optional packages after `npm install` command? Something along the lines of how it is done in [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#suggest)?

There is a [`optionalDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies) entry, but its description looks like a propose of this option is slightly different.

Comment: You could write a `postinstall` script to offer that functionality

Answer (score -1):

cd somedir
npm install .
or

npm install path/to/somedir
somedir must contain the package.json inside it.

It knows about git too:

npm install git://github.com/visionmedia/express.git

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10388874/8814115

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.