# Installing private NPM module over GIT, and having it update?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npm-private-modules

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry) answer, which shows you how to  install npm modules from private git (sub)folders. This works correctly for me when I do:
`npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:myaccount/myprivate.git`, my main application can then call the code in the private module.

But when someone updates the module in the `github.com:myaccount/myprivate.git` location, I want my main application to receive these updated changes.

What I want to do is:

- run `npm install` on the main application
- have it update with the new code in the private module
- ... however the above does NOT update with the new code in the private module

As a work-around I have to:

- run `npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:myaccount/myprivate.git` in the main application
- the new code in the private module is now in the main application
- ... however I don't want to do this for every single application that is calling the private module. If for example 10 applications are calling my one module, that is many places I need to update manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use git commit hashes to keep track of your changes:

```
npm i --save git+ssh://git@github.com:myaccount/myprivate.git#b0f2009
```

or tags

```
npm i --save git+ssh://git@github.com:myaccount/myprivate.git#v0.0.2
```