# How to use local package rather than remote package in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

We have a package from private npm package store. Now we have source code of it and want to use the source code as local package to test something before pushing to repo in dev machine. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a private NPM module without my own registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry)

Comment: It could duplicate but it's other way to resolve the problem, in my case, npm link is good enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use npm link https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Example from the docs

`cd ~/projects/node-redis    # go into the package directory
npm link                    # creates global link
cd ~/projects/node-bloggy   # go into some other package directory.
npm link redis              # link-install the package`

Note that package-name is taken from package.json, not from directory name.

Comment: we also need rebuild package and the host as well

Answer (score 1):

Simply put it in a folder like `__server-root/lib/<module-name>` and require that folder instead of the npm module.

Answer (score 0):

following up the answer of Enslev your `require` could look something like this:

```
const yourPrivateModule = require('./lib/<module-name>/index.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install /path/to/local/package`

This has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry/10388874#10388874)