# Install NPM package globally from a private repository

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I have the following package: [react-native-rename](https://github.com/junedomingo/react-native-rename)

The project, inside *package.json*, has an alias that launches the index.js file.

I forked the repository and uploaded on my private GitLab.

Now, I want to install it globally in my environment.
If I do:

```
npm install -g react-native-rename
```

it works perfectly and I can call react-native-rename from command line. I can see the package installed correctly in the global npm folder.

If I do:

```
npm install -g git+ssh://git@git.company.info:mobile/react-native-rename.git
```

nothing works. Package is not installed and script cannot be called.
Also, this package for some unknown reasons doesn't install without global option.

Any idea about to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a private NPM module without my own registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry)

Comment: No, not really. The problem is different and no solution worked.

Comment: Did anybody find a solution to the problem? I did not find one.

Comment: I didn't. I solved calling directly the index.js file from a local folder containing all the source.

Comment: So anyone found anything? Sounds pretty weird that we still stuck on this.