# npm ERR! code E404 when I install react-admin/ra-enterprise

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-admin

I can not install `react-admin/ra-enterprise` in my project. When I try to install it the below error comes. Actually I try to improve my react-admin.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-admin%2fra-enterprise - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@react-admin/ra-enterprise@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-05T16_04_03_753Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try [@react-admin/ra-enterprise](https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise/modules/ra-enterprise) : `yarn add @react-admin/ra-enterprise` or `npm install @react-admin/ra-enterprise`. ra-enterprise is part of the React-Admin Enterprise Edition, and hosted in a private npm registry. You need to subscribe to one of the Enterprise Edition plans to access this package. See [this](https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise/modules/ra-enterprise)

Comment: hi Ajeet when I try to install the above npm package the above error occurs

Comment: This looks like a private npm package, so you should see [How to install a private NPM module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10386310/2873538). Not sure, but you may need to contact React Admin team for "How to install that private package?". There is "contact" option at [this page](https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise/)

Comment: Found this in their [page](https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise/#pricing): *How do I access the private modules?* Once subscribed, you will receive credentials to download the Enterprise Edition modules from a private npm registry. You can also use these credentials in a CI server.