# React install a private NPM module from Azure DevOps

Tags: reactjs, git, react-native, npm, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up shared npm project library. Was going through the solutions mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386310/how-to-install-a-private-npm-module-without-my-own-registry).
But one difference that I'm facing is like, my repo is inside the Azure DevOps git and git link will come something like this:

> https://<>.visualstudio.com/<poject_name>/_git/AppFolder

I'm planning to follow the exact same methodology of tagging a release of the shared project and use those tags in the package.json like this

> "dependencies": {
> "private-repo": "git+https://<>.visualstudio.com/<poject_name>/_git/AppFolder#v1.0.0",
> }
>
> npm install

But this is failing saying its not a git proper path.

Anyone has any inferences on how this needs to set up in Azure DevOps?